# Dart const variables not bootstrapping correctly

Tags: environment-variables, constants, dart

I have the following Dart project structure:

```
myapp/
    pubspec.yaml
    pubspec.lock
    asset/
    packages/
    build/
    web/
        MyAppClient.dart
        Lookups.dart
```

Here is `MyAppClient.dart`:

```dart
library myapp;

part "Lookups.dart";

// Load/set environmental variables.
// At runtime SERVER_NAME should be "example.com"
String SERVER_NAME = const String.fromEnvironment(Lookups.ENV_VAR_SERVER_NAME);

// Construct all the URL globals used throughout the application. Each of these Strings should
// be visible everywhere in the "myapp" library
String SERVER_BASE_URL_PATTERN = "http://%s/" + Lookups.APP_NAME;
String SERVER_BASE_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL_PATTERN.replaceAll("%s", SERVER_NAME);
String DO_SOMETHING_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL + Lookups.DO_SOMETHING_SERVICE_ENDPOINT;

void main() {
    // Expecting: http://example.com/myapp/doSomething, where "example.com" is the
    // "serverName" env var loaded from String.fromEnvironment.
    window.alert("DO_SOMETHING_URL = $DO_SOMETHING_URL");
}
```

And here is `Lookups.dart`:

```dart
part of myapp;

abstract class Lookups {
    // Environmental variables.
    static const String ENV_VAR_SERVER_NAME = "serverName";

    // HTTP/AJAX/URL lookups.
    static final String APP_NAME = "myapp";
    static final String DO_SOMETHING_SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "/doSomething";
}
```

When I run `pub build` and try to run this in a browser (FF v22.0), the HTML does not display correctly and in Firebug I get an **Illegal Arguments** error. I have a feeling I am not instantiating my global Strings (`DO_SOMETHNG_URL`, etc.) correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `pub build` does not support  the `-D` command line arguments that are used by `dart2js` to handle environment variables. (You can [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new)).

> $ pub build -DserverName=example.com
>
> Could not find an option with short name "-D"

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre Ardhuin (+1) - so what does `pub build` do that `dart2js` doesn't? In other words, what am I losing by abandoning `pub build` for `dart2js` instead? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on what your project uses `pub build` makes different things. So it's not so easy to just abandon `pub build` and that's not what I am recommending.

Comment: Thanks again @Alexandre Ardhuin (+1 again) - so should I run `dart2js` and *then* `pub build`?

Comment: First I would [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new) :) and meanwhile I would try the opposite : first `pub build` and then `dart2js -o ../build/MyAppClient.dart MyAppClient.dart -DserverName=example.com`. But I'm not really sure that it will work.